# How to use derived class variable in baseclass method

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance

I have a hierarchy of classes that inherit from each other that look something like that:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.localLog = logging.getLogger(testName)
        self.var1 = 'a'

    def printVar(self):
        print self.var1

class SubClass1(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 'b'
        super(SubClass1, self).__init__()

class SubClass2(SubClass1):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 'c'
        super(SubClass2, self).__init__()
```

Now I want to instantiate `SubClass2` and call `BaseClass` `printVar` method with `SubClass2` local `var1` variable:

```
obj = SubClass2()
obj.printVar()
```

What I want to happen is for variable `c` climb all the way up to the `BaseClass` and be passed to the `printVar` method. However, what I get is the variable `a` instead.

I realize that I will get the desired result by removing the `super` lines but I have to keep them to have access to the `self.localLog` variable in all inheriting classes.

Is there a way to achieve what I want or should I just keep a local `printVar` method for each class?

Comment: Why are you setting `self.var1` **before** you call `super()`? Doing means that a superclass's definition can override it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are absolutely right! My miss. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you can easily solve the problem simply by calling `super(...).__init__()` *before* setting `var1` in your subclasses.